# Is there an equivalence table between the Desikan-Killiany atlas to brodmann areas?

Tags: neuroimaging, spm

FreeSurfer makes inferences about volume, through the calculation of the surface of the brain. The parametric method (used in SPM) is a voxel-based statistics.

FreeSurfer analysis does not map the brain using the traditional Brodmann's areas (BA) (at least not [entirely](https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/fswiki/BrodmannAreaMaps)), instead it uses the Desikan-Killiany Atlas (DKA).

Researchers that are used to think about the brain regions considering the BAs, may have a hard time to relocate them in terms of DKA. Is there a table with equivalence that one can use in order to translate from one into the other?